# Open .bat file with Python - not working

Tags: python, batch-file

I have 3 different files, one Python file and two .bat files. They communicate between each other (hopefully).

When I execute the "Process_Videos.bat" by itself (double clicking in the windows explorer) it works fine, but whenever I call it from the Python file it doesnt work at all, just says "press any button to continue..."

I really need to have this structure, calling the "Process_Videos.bat" from a Python file, since I am extracting some web info. The "pythonExecute.bat" just works as a trigger for the entire process.

Also I have tried the "subprocess" approach, but not working either.

The files and respective code:

**pythonExecute.bat**

```
python "D:\\tests\\pythonCall.py"
```

**pythonCall.py**

```
import os
os.system('D:\\tests\\3.asc\\Process_Videos_asc.bat')
```

**Process_Videos.bat**

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "FolderBaseName=TestName"
set "DropBoxFolder=D:\tests\3.asc\myDropBoxFolder"
set "BaseOutputFolder=D:\tests\3.asc\TEMP"

for %%I in (*.png) do (

    set "slaveName=%%~nI"
    set "slaveName=!slaveName:~6!
    set "OutputFolder=%BaseOutputFolder%_!slaveName!"
    echo !slaveName!   
    md "!OutputFolder!" 2>nul

    for %%J in (*.mp4*) do (

        ffmpeg -i "%%~fJ" -i "%%~fI" -filter_complex overlay "!OutputFolder!\%%~nJ.mp4"

    )

    "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\rar.exe" a -cfg- -ep1 -inul -m5 "%DropBoxFolder%\%FolderBaseName%_!slaveName!" "!slaveName:~6!\*"

    rd /S /Q "!OutputFolder!"

)

pause
```

Comment: Is the name of your batch file `Process_Videos_asc.bat` or `Process_Videos.bat`?

Comment: Process_Videos.bat, I have that corrected locally, still the same issue tho

Comment: Then it probably because the current working directory is different when you execute it by double-clicking the .bat and invoke via the `pythonCall.py` file — that will make the `for %%I in (*.png) do` not find any files. Add a plain `cd` command to the beginning of `Process_Videos.bat` to print out what the cwd is when it runs (or better yet, add one to change to the proper directory).

Comment: Have a look at my answer in here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54847871/launching-python-script-from-windows-command-line-script-starts-then-fails/56854018#56854018 Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

You need to:

a) Invoke your batch file within the directory it is in, (e.g. by changing directory first), and

b) Get rid of the pause at the end of the batch file.

You should also consider replacing the batch file altogether - python can do all of the things that it does much more neatly.
The accepted answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12204678/simple-example-of-using-ffmpeg-as-a-python-subprocess-and-checking-in-on-the) SO question gives some very good tips.

Comment: What do you mean by the "a)" ? I am writing down everything in absolute paths, not sure if I am understanding correctly.

Comment: (*.png) will be evaluated in the context of the current working directory which if you double click on the batch file will be the same directory as it is stored in, unless you change directory first or use a working directory parameter on subprocess the python will be executing it its directory which I suspect from the absolute paths will not be the same.